# Algolia for Wordpress Multisite

Tags: wordpress, algolia, multisite

Is there any way to use Algolia to index and create a search for sites on a Wordpress Multisite installation?

E.g. so if I was browsing a site in the multisite network, then I could use a searchbox hosted on that site to search for other relevant sites in the multisite network that matched my query.

Answer (score 1):

The plugin will scope the results per website.
There is currently no way of easily creating a "global search" feature.
When in a multi website environment you should make sure you change the index prefix per website.

We have an open issue here https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-wordpress/issues/415 feel free to discuss your use case there.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Elasticsearch and the plugin [ElasticPress](https://github.com/10up/ElasticPress) is able to do this - look for the `sites` parameter in the ElasticPress documentation.